# New component projects created as shared library rather than executable

Tags: redhawksdr

I have been using RedHawk for some time and new Component Project wizard has always created a project that builds to an executable.  Now when I create new Component Projects it builds a shared library.  I can create a new project, generate code with no changes (no ports, properties, etc) and it builds a shared library.  Have I missed some new option that defaults to building a component in the form of a shared library?  I can find no option to choose shared libary vs executable when creating or building.  How do I choose an executable?  I recently upgraded to RedHawk 2.1 and have been working mostly with devices and new device projects do still produce an executable.  I may not have tried a new component project since updating.  Is this something new in 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared library output is the default in REDHAWK 2.1 and provides "Significant enhancement of Component model and BULKIO to support high performance I/O" via the new shared address space model. See the release announcement on the [redhawksdr.org](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/index.html) website or view the component model docs [here](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/blob/develop-2.1/docs/shared-address/component-model.md) for detail.

Comment: Sorry.  I did not notice this in the 2.1 release notes or know about the Component Model doc.  It explains this well and the feature is much as I expected.  I think that this option is great and do not mind it being the default but as the document suggests I think I will still want some components to run in their own memory space.  The document says that that even though the component is a library it CAN be run in its own memory space but I do not see how this option is selected and I do not see any of this in the Manual.  How does one choose to run a component in it own space?

Comment: If you wanted to go back to the old executable pattern, it looks like you just need to modify the spd file and change code type="SharedLibrary" to code type="Executable" then fix the localfile and entrypoint so that they point to the executable name rather than the shared object (eg. remove the .so from both). You will then need to regenerate to create new build files.

Answer (score 0):

To launch a shared-library component as its own process, use the launch function in the Python sandbox, and set shared=False. There is no API to launch a shared-library component as its own process in the context of a domain/waveform.

Threads in ComponentHost (where the shared library component is hosted) are renamed to match whatever components are running on that ComponentHost.